# Error inflating class shape

Tags: android, shapes, layout-inflater

01-23 09:07:52.570: E/AndroidRuntime(2007): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class shape

I got this error while implementing a SHAPE (which is an oval) on my xml file.. what is the problem with this? did I miss something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="10dp" >

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/recName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"    
         />



      <shape  android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
        <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/> </shape>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi, is my solution worked out? if it is use full accept , +1

Answer (score 6):

1) you should not create shape in layout file.

2) you have to create shape file as a part of drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="10dp" >
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/recName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/customdrawable"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Right Click on Drawable folder and create a new android xml in drawable folder:

```
<shape  android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
        <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/> </shape>
```

save this file with customdrawable.xml name

Comment: Its a smart answer Great!

Answer (score 2):

Shape is a `Drawable` not a `View`.

What you'd want to do is create a separate drawable XML file. In your layout use an `ImageView` and set the background to be the drawable file you created.